# PCA: Eigenvectors of opposite sign and not being able to compute eigenvectors with `solve` in R

Tags: r, pca, eigenvalues

I'm learning PCA in R language. I met two problems right now that I don't understand.

1. I am performing a PCA analysis in R on a 318×17 dataset using some custom code.  I take eigen function in R  to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors.  But my 1st and 3rd eigenvectors are of the opposite sign to my handbook.  My second eigenvectors is almost the same.
2. I know that given a square matrix A, the condition that characterizes an eigenvalue, $\lambda$, is the existence of a nonzero vector $x$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$; this equation can be rewritten as follows: $(A - \lambda)x=0$.

   Now I calculate covariance of my data and have eigenvalues. I want to solve this linear combination equation to find $x$ and compare with initial eigenvectors. When I take solve function in R, my $x$ vector is always zero.

**Here are my questions: Why the sign is different? How to use solve function in R  to find a non-zero vector $x$?**

Comment: Regarding the first part of your question, I encountered the same wrinkle when working on this [post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/150978/67822). It came to no surprise that I could have followed through the rest of the derivation with the signs reversed. I don't remember exactly, but it could have amounted to a upper-right quadrant versus lower-left quadrant graphical plotting of the vectors with essentially the same meaning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) The definition of eigenvector $Ax = \lambda x$ is ambidextrous.  If $x$ is an eigenvector, so is $-x$, for then

$$A(-x) = -Ax = -\lambda x = \lambda (-x)$$

So the definition of an eigenbasis is ambiguous of sign.

2) It's hard to know for sure, but I have a strong suspicion of what is happening here.  Your equation

$$ (A - \lambda)x = 0 $$

is technically incorrect.  The correct equation is

$$ (A - \lambda I)x$$

The first equation is often used as a shorthand for the second.  In general, this is unambiguous, because there is no real mathematical way to subtract a vector from a square matrix, but it *is* abuse of notation.  In `R` though, you have broadcasting.  So if you do

```
> M <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1), nrow=2)
> M - .5
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.5  0.5
[2,]  0.5  0.5
```

its not really what you want.  The proper way would be

```
> M - diag(.5, 2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.5  1.0
[2,]  1.0  0.5
```

The reason you are getting zero solutions is that the matrix you are starting with $A$ is invertible.  More than likely (almost surely), the matrix you get by subtracting the same number from every entry will also be invertible.  For invertible matrices, the only solution to $Ax = 0$ is the zero vector.

Comment: Thanks @ Matthew Drry . You're right my equation is used as a shorthand for the second.  It's true that if A is invertible, Ax=0 can be written as x=0*A(-1).So x is always zero vector. As I mentioned,the condition that characterizes an eigenvalue, λ, is the existence of a nonzero vector x such that Ax=λx.  How R can find a nonzero vector x?Because when i took eigen function, I got nonzero eigenvectors.Does it mean that behind eigen function, R find eigenvectors by another way which is not the solve function?

Comment: @KrollDU You won't be able to use solve to recover the eigenvectors, because `solve` is designed for *non-singular* systems, and the eigenvector system is, by design, singular.  So no, R does not use `solve` internally in it's `eigen` computation.  You can check this by looking at the source code for `eigen`, where you'll find `z <- if (!complex.x).Internal(La_rs(x, only.values))`

Comment: Looks like `La_rs` is a C function calling into a fortran routine, you can find it here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/4adf54a3a9d92993f1d827396d7eb6cf6b60dbf7/src/modules/lapack/Lapack.c

Comment: @ Matthew Drury, You're right. Solve function can't be used to recover the eigenvectors.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @ Mathew if  the definition of an eigenbasis is ambiguous of sign, what's the impact to the final result?

Comment: @KrollDU Could you clarify that last question?  What do you mean by *impact to the final result*?