# Why do prcomp() and eigen(cov()) in R return different signs of PCA eigenvectors?

Tags: r, pca, svd, eigenvalues, numerics

I understand the sign of the eigen vectors / PCA rotations can be positive or negative (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154716/pca-eigenvectors-of-opposite-sign-and-not-being-able-to-compute-eigenvectors-wi?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88880/does-the-sign-of-scores-or-of-loadings-in-pca-or-fa-have-a-meaning-may-i-revers?rq=1)).

But I am curious why the following two approaches yield different results, from numerical method perspective?

```
> d = iris[,1:2]
> pca = prcomp(d)
> r = eigen(cov(d))
> r$vectors
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] -0.99640834 -0.08467831
[2,]  0.08467831 -0.99640834
> pca$rotation
                     PC1        PC2
Sepal.Length  0.99640834 0.08467831
Sepal.Width  -0.08467831 0.99640834
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is an exact duplicate - although it is closely related. (OP here *already knows that eigenvectors are only defined up to a change in sign*, wants to know why different computational approaches give different answers ...)

Comment: @Ben You might be right, but this issue has come up so many times I'm sure there's a duplicate around somewhere.  In the meantime because I was certain it would be closed as a dup eventually, I wanted to close it as a dup of *something.*  (+1 for your answer, BTW: it adds a welcome computing perspective to the other answers I recall seeing.)

Comment: Note that a PCA function (prcomp in this instance) might be adjusting the sign _after_ the eigendecompsition. Often, a PCA function will change the sign of eigenverctors so that the sum in each eigenvector is positive. Just for convenience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the code, `stats:::prcomp.default` uses singular value decomposition at its core, rather than eigendecomposition of the variance-covariance matrix.

In general, the computed signs of eigenvectors can be *very* sensitive to small computational differences: according to [Brian Ripley on R-help in 2003](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-July/036504.html),

> using different compilers on the same machine and the 
>   same version of R may give different signs for the eigenvectors.  The 
>   moral is, don't rely on the signs of eigenvectors!  (This *is* on the help 
>   page.)

That is, it's not just `prcomp` (SVD) vs. `eigen`; the results could differ for `eigen` across operating systems, compilers, possibly even floating-point hardware ...

Comment: Could you tell me why? The results could differ for eigen across operating systems, compilers, possibly even floating-point hardware? where is the "randomness" in the different systems?

Comment: @hxd1011 I do not think it is random. The same software on the same OS on the same computer will give the same result but changing one of them may give a different result.

Comment: @mdewey thanks, but why different system will be different? is ieee 754 is implemented differently cross OS? like TCP IP stack?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. See e.g. http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/addendum.html

Comment: @Ben, The claim in your answer is extremely important. One thing is when different functions/programs give different signs. Another thing (potentially threatening) is that on different OS or computers the results will be sign-different. Can you support with evidence your claim?

Comment: Well, you could take Brian Ripley's word for it :-) ... I don't have the time to run around trying `eigen()` on different OS/computers at the moment, but I'm sure it's true. The point here is that *there are certain aspects of floating-point math that are not stable across platforms* - knowing which ones is important.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but it's happened to me recently and I have found a solution that seems to work. I guess is due the internals of prcomp and eigen as pointed out in a previous comment, but if you want eigen to produce the same eigenvectors as prcomp it seems using the flag symmetric = FALSE does the trick:

```
> d = iris[,1:2]
> pca = prcomp(d)
> r = eigen(cov(d), symmetric = FALSE)
> r$vectors
            [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.99640834 0.08467831
[2,] -0.08467831 0.99640834
> pca$rotation
                     PC1        PC2
Sepal.Length  0.99640834 0.08467831
Sepal.Width  -0.08467831 0.99640834
>
```

I hope this is useful for someone else.